# How to stop postgres from autostarting during start up

Tags: postgresql

I have postgresql 8.4 installed on my desktop. It keeps starting on bootup because I think I used default settings.

so I issue `/etc/init.d/postgresql stop` everytime and sometimes i keep forgetting

It has folder paths as,

```
/etc/postgresql/8.4/main
/usr/lib/postgresql/8.4
```

There are a lot of configuration files and if someone can tell me where to look and what to change, that will be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can help you: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-remove-postgresql-from-startup-481963/#post2417585

But install chkconfig first:

```
sudo apt-get install chkconfig
```

and then use it

```
chkconfig
```

Comment: `update-rc.d` is more native for Debian.

Comment: You're welcome :) Check out this link http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-manage-services-with-update-rc.d too.Thanks to ulidtko.

Comment: Using systemctl (see other answers) is intended method when using systemd, e.g. on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 46):

On Ubuntu 16.04 or later (which use systemd) you'd use this command

```
sudo systemctl disable postgresql
```

If you want to re-enable, you'd do

```
sudo systemctl enable postgresql
```

On Ubuntu 15.10 and older, you can use `update-rc.d`:

```
janus@Zeus:~$ sudo update-rc.d -f postgresql remove
 Removing any system startup links for /etc/init.d/postgresql ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K21postgresql
   /etc/rc1.d/K21postgresql
   /etc/rc2.d/S19postgresql
   /etc/rc3.d/S19postgresql
   /etc/rc4.d/S19postgresql
   /etc/rc5.d/S19postgresql
   /etc/rc6.d/K21postgresql
janus@Zeus:~$
```

Comment: this is the proper way to do what was requested

Comment: And if you want to do both stop and disable, you can simply do `sudo systemctl disable --now postgresql`. See `man systemctl` for details. Similarly you can add `--now` flag to the command `enable`, too.

Answer (score 7):

Using `update-rc.d` is better but you can do it with `chkconfig`:

```
sudo apt-get install chkconfig
sudo chkconfig -s  postgresql off
```

In Ubuntu 12.04, you also need to create a symlink to `insserv`'s location:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/insserv/insserv /sbin/insserv
```

Comment: I had to create the symlink using 10.10 as well. In addition I got this large output as a response: http://pastebin.com/fPKRj5Gr

Answer (score 5):

The answers in here are outdated. Take a look at [Daniel Vérité's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/31239) on [Preventing PostgreSQL from starting on boot in Ubuntu -  Database Administrators Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/31210).

> Ubuntu or Debian can run multiple instances of PostgreSQL and provide
>   a specific way to autostart/stop/start each cluster.
>
> There should be a file named `start.conf` inside
>   `/etc/postgresql/9.2/main` (or more generally
>   /etc/postgresql/<*version*>/<*clustername*>) with these
>   self-explanatory contents:
>
> ```
> # Automatic startup configuration
> # auto: automatically start/stop the cluster in the init script
> # manual: do not start/stop in init scripts, but allow manual startup with
> #         pg_ctlcluster
> # disabled: do not allow manual startup with pg_ctlcluster (this can be easily
> #           circumvented and is only meant to be a small protection for
> #           accidents).
>
> auto
> ```
>
> If you replace *auto* by *manual*, you could start this PostgreSQL
>   instance only when desired with the command:
>
> ```
> sudo pg_ctlcluster 9.2 main start
> ```
>
> As for looking at the console, what you should want instead is having
>   this run in a terminal when you work with the database:
>
> ```
> tail -f /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.2-main.log
> ```

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers to other Stack Exchange questions. Instead, include the essential portions of the answer here, and *tailor the answer to this specific question.*

Answer (score -1):

On my server there is another effect:

```
# update-rc.d -f postgresql remove
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
```

No system startup links were removed.